# What's the right regex to exclude a large number?

Tags: regex, grep

I need to grep through a server's access log for lines that do not contain the number `12345` but *do* contain the word `omgspecialword`.

What's the regex that will allow me to grep for these lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex if the number and the word are fixed, just use `|` to pipe and filter your results through 2 different `grep`'s

```
cat file_name | grep -v 12345 | grep omgspecialword
```

Explanation:

`cat file_name |` - `cat` prints the content of `file_name` and pipes it into the next segment

`grep -v 12345 |` excludes the lines that contain matching pattern `12345`, then pipes the result into the next segment

`grep omgspecialword` filters the lines that contain matching pattern `omgspecialword`. Since it's not piped into anything else here, this is printed to stdout.

Comment: So, it's okay to pipe results across multiple `grep`s? I think I was told once that that's not very efficient or frowned upon. I never bothered to look it up, though.

Comment: Unless you are working with very large files and you need to optimize performance, it's generally not a big deal.

Comment: What's a "very large" file? The log in question has like 4 million lines

Comment: How often do you need to run this script against the log? How often does this log update? Does the log just get appended to or does all 4 million lines change each time you need to the run the script against it? Is it possible to break up the log? Do you know approximately what % of lines will need to be output (I assume that you will write the output to a file, which has additional I/O overhead)? The are a number of technical considerations. However, pipes and filters is not like batch-sequential, the output from one grep is passed as input to the next grep as it's processed; it's efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep 'omgspecialword' your_file|grep -v 12345
```

or

```
awk '$0!~/12345/ && /omgspecialword/' your_file
```

or

```
perl -lne 'if(/omgspecialword/ && !(/12345/)){print}' your_file
```